# Bitcoin sent to Bitcoin Cash address in blockchain

Tags: blockchain.info

I sent bitcoin to a bitcoin cash address in my blockchain account. Are the coins going to the account and if not what if anything can I do to recover my bitcoins?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the private key of the bitcoin cash address, you can import it into your bitcoin wallet and send it somewhere else.
If not, you have to ask the one, who has its private key, for example an exchange.